# C++ freestanding features

Tags: c++, gcc4.7, freestanding

What are the features that I can use in c++ freestanding environment? I am developing a little kernel (for my own pleasure) and I know that I can't use the whole stdlib library, but what else ? when I tried to use the new and delete operators it compiled without troubles but the linker said

```
undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned long)
undefined reference to `operator delete[](void*)'
```

I link with `-lgcc` and `-lsupc++` options. I know that exception handling is disable in freestanding but I am a little bit surprised that new and delete are also. So what can I use and what can I not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What are the features that I can use in c++ freestanding environment?

Much of freestanding implementations is implementation defined:

> [intro.compliance] ... A freestanding
>   implementation is one in which execution may take place without the benefit of an operating system, and
>   has an implementation-defined set of libraries that includes certain language-support libraries
>
> [intro.multithread] ... Under a freestanding implementation, it is implementation-defined whether
>   a program can have more than one thread of execution.
>
> [basic.start.main] It
>   is implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main
>   function. [ Note: In a freestanding environment, start-up and termination is implementation-defined; start-
>   up contains the execution of constructors for objects of namespace scope with static storage duration;
>   termination contains the execution of destructors for objects with static storage duration. — end note ]
>
> [using.headers] C ++ headers for freestanding implementations
>
> ```
> <ciso646>
> <cstddef>
> <cfloat>
> <limits>
> <climits>
> <cstdint>
> <cstdlib>
> <new>
> <typeinfo>
> <exception>
> <initializer_list>
> <cstdalign>
> <cstdarg>
> <cstdbool>
> <atomic>
> ```
>
> [compliance] The supplied version of the header `<cstdlib>` shall declare at least the functions abort, atexit, at_quick_-
>   exit, exit, and quick_exit (18.5). The other headers listed in this table shall meet the same requirements
>   as for a hosted implementation.

Note that `malloc`/`free` are not listed in the required functions of `<cstdlib>`.

---

As far as your linker error is concerned, neither freestanding, nor hosted implementation is required to provide those overloads:

> [replacement.functions] A C ++ program **may** provide the definition for any of twelve dynamic memory allocation function signatures
>   declared in header `<new>`

In practice, since a free standing environment cannot depend on an OS, and `malloc` is usually implemented using features provided by an OS, it is unlikely to have free store memory management features in a freestanding environment. Conversely, a hosted environment requires free store memory management to implement the features of the standard library.